# Laravel 5 Broadcast Event to WildCard Channel using Node and Laravel-Echo-Server

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, node-redis

I have two roles, Doctors, and Patients...

When a Patient does action A, I want a broadcast to go out to a list of Doctors, not All of the Doctors, but a list of them..

In my testing, I was able to accomplish this by subscribing with redis in node to channels prefixed with Doctor and a hyphen then UserID...

```
redis.subscribe('Doctor-1', function(err, count) {
});
```

However, for production, I can not hardcode that ID, what I need is something like the following

```
redis.subscribe('Doctor-*', function(err, count) {
});
```

But the wildcard does not seem to work...

Any ideas on how I can subscribe to a wildcard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Redis.io, PubSub Documentation](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub)

[Wikipedia, Glob Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

> The Redis Pub/Sub implementation supports pattern matching. Clients
>   may subscribe to glob-style patterns in order to receive all the
>   messages sent to channel names matching a given pattern.
>
> For instance:

```
PSUBSCRIBE news.*
```

So your snippet could change to

```
redis.subscribe('Doctor.*', function(err, count) {});
```

So it will receive any for Doctor with ID `Doctor.1` or more in depth

`Doctors.<groupId>.<DoctorId>` and so on.